# Application onLowMemory in Emulator 2.3 and not in 2.2 in android?

Tags: android, emulation

I am facing an issue where the app if run in android emulator 2.3 the logcat shows low memory and then the memory stack and the emulator is restarted then. But the app works fine in emulator 2.2. I have checked in the device with OS 2.3 and the app does work properly in the device, but its the emulator that is giving this problem.

Can there be any problem with the emulator 2.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase size of memory of emulator in AVD manager,

```
Window->Android SDK and AVD manager-> emulator->Edit->Increase memory space
```